# how to highlight the navigation bar using only HTML, CSS and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to make the navigation bar items in this code to be highlighted while their corresponding sections are brought into view using only HTML, CSS and Javascript. I mean I shouldn't use any libraries or frameworks and no HTML5 or CSS3. Some people told me to use something called "scroll spy", but after looking it up and doing some trials, I couldn't use it in my code, it didn't give the desired outcome. So please help me with it.
here's the HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Manipulating the DOM</title>
  <!-- Load Google Fonts -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fira+Sans:900|Merriweather&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">  <!-- Load Styles -->
  <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <!-- HTML Follows BEM naming conventions 
  IDs are only used for sections to connect menu achors to sections -->
  <header class="page__header">
    <nav class="navbar__menu">
      <!-- Navigation starts as empty UL that will be populated with JS -->
      <ul id="navbar__list"></ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <main>
    <header class="main__hero">
      <h1>Landing Page </h1>
    </header>
    <!-- Each Section has an ID (used for the anchor) and 
    a data attribute that will populate the li node.
    Adding more sections will automatically populate nav.
    The first section is set to active class by default -->
    <section id="section1" data-nav="Section 1" class="your-active-class">
      <div class="landing__container">
        <h2>Section 1</h2>
        <p>dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi fermentum metus faucibus lectus pharetra dapibus. Suspendisse potenti. Aenean aliquam elementum mi, ac euismod augue. Donec eget lacinia ex. Phasellus imperdiet porta orci eget mollis. Sed convallis sollicitudin mauris ac tincidunt. Donec bibendum, nulla eget bibendum consectetur, sem nisi aliquam leo, ut pulvinar quam nunc eu augue. Pellentesque maximus imperdiet elit a pharetra. Duis lectus mi, aliquam in mi quis, aliquam porttitor lacus. Morbi a tincidunt felis. Sed leo nunc, pharetra et elementum non, faucibus vitae elit. Integer nec libero venenatis libero ultricies molestie semper in tellus. Sed congue et odio sed euismod.</p>

        <p>a convallis justo. Vivamus venenatis, erat eget pulvinar gravida, ipsum lacus aliquet velit, vel luctus diam ipsum a diam. Cras eu tincidunt arcu, vitae rhoncus purus. Vestibulum fermentum consectetur porttitor. Suspendisse imperdiet porttitor tortor, eget elementum tortor mollis non.</p>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section id="section2" data-nav="Section 2">
      <div class="landing__container">
        <h2>Section 2</h2>
        <p>ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi fermentum metus faucibus lectus pharetra dapibus. Suspendisse potenti. Aenean aliquam elementum mi, ac euismod augue. Donec eget lacinia ex. Phasellus imperdiet porta orci eget mollis. Sed convallis sollicitudin mauris ac tincidunt. Donec bibendum, nulla eget bibendum consectetur, sem nisi aliquam leo, ut pulvinar quam nunc eu augue. Pellentesque maximus imperdiet elit a pharetra. Duis lectus mi, aliquam in mi quis, aliquam porttitor lacus. Morbi a tincidunt felis. Sed leo nunc, pharetra et elementum non, faucibus vitae elit. Integer nec libero venenatis libero ultricies molestie semper in tellus. Sed congue et odio sed euismod.</p>

        <p>a convallis justo. Vivamus venenatis, erat eget pulvinar gravida, ipsum lacus aliquet velit, vel luctus diam ipsum a diam. Cras eu tincidunt arcu, vitae rhoncus purus. Vestibulum fermentum consectetur porttitor. Suspendisse imperdiet porttitor tortor, eget elementum tortor mollis non.</p>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section id="section3" data-nav="Section 3">
      <div class="landing__container">
        <h2>Section 3</h2>
        <p>ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi fermentum metus faucibus lectus pharetra dapibus. Suspendisse potenti. Aenean aliquam elementum mi, ac euismod augue. Donec eget lacinia ex. Phasellus imperdiet porta orci eget mollis. Sed convallis sollicitudin mauris ac tincidunt. Donec bibendum, nulla eget bibendum consectetur, sem nisi aliquam leo, ut pulvinar quam nunc eu augue. Pellentesque maximus imperdiet elit a pharetra. Duis lectus mi, aliquam in mi quis, aliquam porttitor lacus. Morbi a tincidunt felis. Sed leo nunc, pharetra et elementum non, faucibus vitae elit. Integer nec libero venenatis libero ultricies molestie semper in tellus. Sed congue et odio sed euismod.</p>

        <p>a convallis justo. Vivamus venenatis, erat eget pulvinar gravida, ipsum lacus aliquet velit, vel luctus diam ipsum a diam. Cras eu tincidunt arcu, vitae rhoncus purus. Vestibulum fermentum consectetur porttitor. Suspendisse imperdiet porttitor tortor, eget elementum tortor mollis non.</p>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section id="section4" data-nav="Section 4">
      <div class="landing__container">
        <h2>Section 4</h2>
        <p>ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi fermentum metus faucibus lectus pharetra dapibus. Suspendisse potenti. Aenean aliquam elementum mi, ac euismod augue. Donec eget lacinia ex. Phasellus imperdiet porta orci eget mollis. Sed convallis sollicitudin mauris ac tincidunt. Donec bibendum, nulla eget bibendum consectetur, sem nisi aliquam leo, ut pulvinar quam nunc eu augue. Pellentesque maximus imperdiet elit a pharetra. Duis lectus mi, aliquam in mi quis, aliquam porttitor lacus. Morbi a tincidunt felis. Sed leo nunc, pharetra et elementum non, faucibus vitae elit. Integer nec libero venenatis libero ultricies molestie semper in tellus. Sed congue et odio sed euismod.</p>

        <p>a convallis justo. Vivamus venenatis, erat eget pulvinar gravida, ipsum lacus aliquet velit, vel luctus diam ipsum a diam. Cras eu tincidunt arcu, vitae rhoncus purus. Vestibulum fermentum consectetur porttitor. Suspendisse imperdiet porttitor tortor, eget elementum tortor mollis non.</p>
      </div>
    </section>
  </main>
  <footer class="page__footer">
    <p>&copy Udacity</p>
  </footer>
  <script src = "js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the CSS code

```
/* ---- Base Rules ---- */
body {
    background: rgb(136,203,171);
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(136,203,171,1) 0%, rgba(0,13,60,1) 100%);
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
    color: #fff;
}


/* Typeography General*/
h1 {
    font-family: 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 3em;
    margin: 2em 1rem;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 35em){
    h1 {
        font-size: 7em;
        margin: 2em 4rem 1em;
    }
}

h2 {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #cc1;
    font-family: 'Oxygen', Sans-Serif;
    font-size: 3em;
    color: #fff;
}

p {
    line-height: 1.6em;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

/* ---- Layout Rules ---- */
main {
    margin: 10vh 1em 10vh;
}

.main-hero {
    min-height: 40vh;
    padding-top: 3em;
}

section {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 80vh;
}


/* ---- Module Rules ---- */

/* Navigation Styles*/
.navbar__menu ul {
    padding-left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: left;
}

.navbar__menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color:green;
    color: honeydew;
}

.navbar__menu .menu__link {
    display: block;
    padding: 1em;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
.navbar__menu .menu__link:hover .active {
    background: #333;
    color: #fff;
    transition: ease 0.3s all;
}
.active{
    background: black;
}
/* Header Styles */
.page__header {
    background: green;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 5;
}

/* Footer Styles */
.page__footer {
    background: #000;
    padding: 3em;
    color: #fff;
}

.page__footer p{
    color: #fff;
}


/* ---- Theme Rules ---- */
/* Landing Container Styles */
.landing__container {
    padding: 1em;
    text-align: left;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 35em){
    .landing__container {
        max-width: 50em;
        padding: 4em;
    }
}

section:nth-of-type(even) .landing__container {
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    text-align: right; 
}

/* Background Circles */
/* Note that background circles are created with psuedo elements before and after */
/* Circles appear to be random do to use of :nth-of-type psuedo class */
section:nth-of-type(odd) .landing__container::before {
    content: '';
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.187);
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -5;
    width: 20vh;
    height: 20vh;
    border-radius: 50%;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: ease 0.5s all;
}

section:nth-of-type(even) .landing__container::before {
    content: '';
    background: rgb(255,255,255);
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255,255,255,.1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,.2) 100%);
    position: absolute;
    top: 3em;
    right: 3em;
    z-index: -5;
    width: 10vh;
    height: 10vh;
    border-radius: 50%;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: ease 0.5s all;
}

section:nth-of-type(3n) .landing__container::after {
    content: '';
    background: rgb(255,255,255);
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255,255,255,.1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,.2) 100%);
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: -5;
    width: 10vh;
    height: 10vh;
    border-radius: 50%;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: ease 0.5s all;
}

section:nth-of-type(3n + 1) .landing__container::after {
    content: '';
    background: rgb(255,255,255);
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255,255,255,.1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,.2) 100%);
    position: absolute;
    right: 20vw;
    bottom: -5em;
    z-index: -5;
    width: 15vh;
    height: 15vh;
    border-radius: 50%;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: ease 0.5s all;
}


/* ---- Theme State Rules ---- */
/* Section Active Styles */
/* Note: your-active-class class is applied through javascript. You should update the class here and in the index.html to what you set in your javascript file.  */
section.your-active-class {
    background-color: #cc1;
}
section.your-active-class .landing__container::before {
    opacity: 1;
    animation: rotate 4s linear 0s infinite forwards;
}

section.your-active-class .landing__container::after {
    opacity: 1;
    animation: rotate 5s linear 0s infinite forwards reverse;
}

/* Section Active Styles Keyframe Animations */
@keyframes rotate {
    from {
        transform: rotate(0deg)
                   translate(-1em)
                   rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        transform: rotate(360deg)
                   translate(-1em) 
                   rotate(-360deg);
    }
html {
        scroll-behavior: smooth;
      }
}
```

and here's the Javascript code

```
//create navigation menu
//make navigation menu buttons scroll into section
const sections = document.querySelectorAll('section');
const list = document.querySelector('ul');
const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
for (const section of sections){
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    const sect = section.getAttribute('data-nav');
    const name = section.getAttribute('id');
    li.innerHTML = `<a class="menu__link">${sect}</a>`;
    list.appendChild(li);
    fragment.appendChild(li);
    li.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        section.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"})
    })
}
list.appendChild(fragment);
//making active section's highlighted in yellow
window.addEventListener('scroll',() => {
    const option =
        {
          root: null,
          threshold:0.7,
          rootMargin:'0px'
        };
      //Using the IntersectionObserver to get the active section
        const observer = new IntersectionObserver(function (entries, observer) { 
          entries.forEach((entry) =>
          {
  
            if(entry.isIntersecting)//If section is in viewport
            {
              
              //adding active classes to the section in view
              entry.target.classList.add("your-active-class");
          }
            else
            {
              // we are EXITING the "capturing frame" so we remove the active class
              entry.target.classList.remove("your-active-class");
              //if section is not visible we don't observe it anymore
              observer.unobserve(entry.target);
            }
            console.log(entry.target);
          });
        }, option);
          //doing this to all sections
          sections.forEach((section) => {
            //activate observer to observe sections
          observer.observe(section);
        });
      });
```

Comment: Why would you ask about using "only" HTML, CSS, and JS? Once you add in JS, you can literally do anything you want on a page, there is no "only" anymore, this is the full stack the browser works with =)

Comment: I mean no libraries, frameworks and no HTML5 or CSS3. Question edited with this comment

Comment: But modern HTML and CSS _are_ HTML5 and CSS3. Those are simply the current versions of those two language specs. Not using the current versions would be a little ridiculous (HTML 4.01 and CSS2 were replaced many, _many_ years ago. Heck, CSS2 was replaced over 20 years ago).

Comment: It's an assignment for practicing only HTML, CSS and Javascript. so using any libraries or frameworks won't let the assignment get accepted. and since I'm new into web development I don't have anything up my sleeve. That's why I'm asking for help

Comment: @AutisitcWebDeveloper HTML5 and CSS3 aren't libraries, they are the standard. You'd want to use them if you're doing any web dev at all.

Comment: @devsandbox well, right now I just need this assignment to get accepted. It's not about web development....It's about graduation...

Comment: @AutisitcWebDeveloper Yes, and you should at least understand the difference between HTML5, CSS3 and libraries if you're graduating. Good luck. The answer below should give you what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're very close! Good call with IntersectionObserver! That's a good native method for this kind of thing.

Basically, you can add an attribute that has the id of the corresponding section to your links

```
for (const section of sections) {
  const li = document.createElement("li");
  const name = section.getAttribute("data-nav"); //// CHANGED
  const sectId = section.getAttribute("id"); //// CHANGED
  li.innerHTML = `<a class="menu__link" data-selects="${sectId}" href="${sectId}">${name}</a>`; //// CHANGED
```

and then select them by that attribute in your IntersectionObserver:

```
entries.forEach((entry) => {
      let correspondingNavItem = document.querySelector(
        //// ADDED
        `[data-selects="${entry.target.id}"]`
      );

     if (entry.isIntersecting) {
        //If section is in viewport
        //adding active classes to the section in view
        entry.target.classList.add("your-active-class");

        correspondingNavItem.classList.add("selected-link"); //// ADDED
        correspondingNavItem.setAttribute("aria-current", true); //// ADDED
```

I modified your code in this codepen to show you how this could work: https://codepen.io/karlyanelson/pen/LYWaJyR

Note: the `aria-current` is to help with accessibility. [You can learn more about aria-current here](https://www.digitala11y.com/aria-current-state/).

Also, to make your links in your navigation actually accessible (ie: able to be used by just a keyboard or screenreader), then they need a valid href. You can just pass in the id of the section you want them to navigate to.